# Dropzone displaying icons before upload

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, dropzone.js

I'm attempting to use [dropzone.js](http://dropzonejs.com) for an ASP.NET MVC 5 app and I'm getting some weird display behavior.

Dropzone is being added to an existing form. I have the the `autoProcessQueue` set to `false` because I want the user to have to click the `Submit` button. After adding the files to the dropzone, the thumbnail appears with two icons below it. One is a checkbox and the other is an X. They look like maybe success and failure icons. Check out this picture:

[image]

I also notice that I don't get the progress bar animation when the user clicks the file. What's going on here? Do I have dropzone configured wrong?

Here is the code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@model WebApplication1.Controllers.TestViewModel

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.3.0/dropzone.css">

<form id="form" method="post" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="Field1" />
    <select name="Field2">
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
        <option>C</option>
    </select>
    <div id="dz-message">
        drop file here
    </div>
    <input id="submit" type="submit"/>
</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.3.0/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

        var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#form", {
            url: "/Home/Upload",
            paramName: "Field3",
            autoProcessQueue: false,
            maxFiles: 1,
            clickable: true,

            init: function () {
                var dropzone = this;

                this.element.querySelector("#submit").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    dropzone.processQueue();
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, palm to forehead. I just didn't have the `dropzone` class on the `form` element. Took it off earlier to try something and forgot to put it back on.

Rar.